# Who can see Facebook tags before I have approved them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I was recently tagged in a Facebook status update, and thankfully I have my "tagging review" enabled.

So essentially, my question is, if I was tagged in something, and I haven't approved it yet, would MY friends (people who have NO mutual friends with the tagger) see that status update?

Comment: It depends on the privacy settings on the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you've not approved the status it won't show on your wall. then your friends cant see it if they are not mutual with the tagger.

It will only show on tagger's wall and other people tagged (if any) in status and approved the same.